# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{k = n}^{2n}\dfrac{\pi}{2\tan^{-1}k} = 4^{1/\pi}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi

[MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html) states that (see equation $(130)$) $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{k = n}^{2n}\dfrac{\pi}{2\tan^{-1}k} = 4^{1/\pi}$$ and attributes it to Gosper. I believe an approach to establish the formula is to take logs to get $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = n}^{2n}\log\left(\frac{\pi}{2\tan^{-1}k}\right) = \frac{\log 4}{\pi}$$ But I have not been able to express the LHS as as integral. Perhaps some manipulation of the LHS is needed. Any proof or hints would be helpful.

Comment: Hint: $\tan^{-1}k = \frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{k}$.

Comment: @achillehui: let me try that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT:** $$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = n}^{2n}\log\left(\frac{\pi}{2\tan^{-1}k}\right)= \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = n}^{2n}\log\left(\frac{\pi}{2\left(\frac\pi2-\tan^{-1}\frac1k\right)}\right)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = n}^{2n}\log\left(1+\frac{2}{\pi k}\right)$$ due to $$ \tan^{-1}\frac1k=\frac1k+O(\frac{1}{k^3})$$ as $k$ is great.

**Edit:** Since, for $\alpha>1$, each series of the form $$\sum_{k =1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{\alpha}} $$ is convergent, then we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = n}^{2n}O(\frac{1}{k^{\alpha}})=0$$ and we are allowed to write the second equality above.

Comment: before I could try the hint from achille hui, you gave it. +1. I will accept this.

Comment: Of course, the *second* equality sign should be carefully motivated since using equivalents in sums with unbounded numbers of terms is a sure way to go astray.

Comment: @Did: I fully agree. It requires some experience to know which terms to neglect and which ones not. But I believe this answer was more of a hint so it is OK.

Comment: @Did Yes, please see the edit. Thanx!